# How to display list of high score both on device and globally

Tags: java, android, android-savedstate

I have read several tutorials but can't pin down exactly what I need

I am trying to add a list of high score(about 10 rows) from people that have played the game on my device, then in another tab, I want to have list of high scores from players around the world.

Currently what I have now is just a row with a saved-pref high score, while the name was inputted manually(how do I save each high score with a name?)

This is an image of what I have

[image]

This is an image of what I require

[image]

what I need is

1. How do I save a name with each high score?
2. How do I save my list of 10 row high score?(with an array i'm guessing?)
3. How do I populate my leader board tab with the 10 highest scores globally?(also with names each)

my codes are below

**Gamepanel.java**

this is where I save the high score, each new high score overrides the previous one, but instead i need a list to be made.

```
private void setBestScore(int bestScore) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getContext().getSharedPreferences("gamepanel", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putInt("bestScore", bestScore);
    editor.apply();
}
```

**Tab1.java**

This is where I retrieve saved highscore

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Returning the layout file after inflating
    //Change R.layout.tab1 in you classes
    View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container,false);

    TextView tv = (TextView) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText("Name:"+ " Ken");

    TextView t = (TextView) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    t.setText("Score: " +getBestScore());

    return myInflatedView;

}

protected int getBestScore() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("gamepanel", MODE_PRIVATE);
    return prefs.getInt("bestScore", 0);
}
```

Please I would appreciate any help or any step forward on how to go about this

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are already familiar with usage of shared preferences, as you are using them to store the best score. I'd suggest first to get more familiar with the concepts of possible storage options that Android currently supports:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

You want your data to stay persistent on the device, simple array/ArrayList or any other data collection can only be used to be stored in the memory for the time being of immediate usage. It will exist as long as your application is in use and will be purged soon afterward, as soon as Android realizes, that it is no longer needed. The above documentation describes possible options to store the data permanently.

Basically, shared preferences is one of your choices and this way you are able to store simple pairs of key-values, that will be persistent on the device. If you want, it is possible this way to store arrays of data as well, but I don't really think this way can be recommended. Shared preferences are great for simple, single values to be stored and reused, especially if they are not updated frequently. For any collection of different values, I would recommend a simple SQLite database:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

They are very lightweight, so they aren't adding really much load for your game and it could also store additional data for you, if you will expend your game. You can then read any number of previous high scores, as you can choose to store only 10 values, but you can also store more and choose to display only 10. In this case, you could for instance load 10 top hits from the DB, store them in local memory as an array and display in a simple ListView.

Now, when it comes to storing the values globally - I assume you are thinking about the Global Leaderboards? In this case you would need to have an external server storing all the top high scores, the application is only a client and cannot talk directly to other clients (as it cannot talk to ALL clients at the same time). The system needs a server, that is centralized and retrieves information from the client apps, and then shares the information with them. This is far more complex than a single answer could explain, so I believe you will have to read little more about building the server and how the apps can talk with it (through REST APIs for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Using SharedPreferences for this purpose isn't so useful for you.
I suggest to use database. Android has as DBMS Sqlite. If you don't know what are they here there is a simple guide.

[DBMS and relationship database](http://www.eazynotes.com/pages/database-management-system/introduction-to-dbms.html)

Then you have to know that to insert and query data from a database there is a standard language called SQL(Structured query language i guess)

[Introduction to sql](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

Then you have to know if you don't that android as DBMS use Sqlite and from your java code you can use it to store and query data.

Here there is a little guide

[SQLite android](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/783073/A-Simple-Android-SQLite-Example)

I hope to have been helpful for you.